# System of Linear Equations with integer Coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the following system of linear equation:

\begin{align}
  2a + 4b &= a + 3c\\
  2a + 3b &= 4a + 2b\\
  4a + 2b &= b + nc
\end{align}

for $a,b,c \in \mathbf{R}_{+}$.

How do I find the value of $n \in \mathbf{N}$, assuming there is a unique solution for $(a,b,c)$?

(I guess substitution is the way to go but I can't figure it out.)

Comment: You're not assuming it has a unique solution. You're assuming it has infinitely many solutions i.e. you're assuming it has a solution other than (0,0,0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 2nd equation, $b=2a$.

From the 1st equation, $9a=3c$ so $c=3a$.

From the 3rd equation, $8a=2a+3na$ so $3n=6$ (since $a\ne0$) and $n=2$.

Comment: Nice and simple!

Answer (score 1):

The determinant {{1,4,-3},{-2, 1, 0},{4, 1, -n}} is $18-9n$.
What you want is this determinant to be $0$. So $n=2$.

[determinant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant%20of%20%7B%7B1,4,-3%7D,%7B-2,%201,%200%7D,%20%7B4,%201,%20-n%7D%7D)

Answer (score 0):

See as $0$  is the solution any value of $n $ satisfies it but now if we have some solution apart from $0$ then use determinants. For this system the determinant of third order should be equal to $0$ if you plug values you get a solution ie $9n=18$ thus $n=2$ has solution which is not $[0,0,0]$

Comment: Can you write it out, please? I don't really get it ... sorry.

Comment: I am not sure where $9n=18$ came from.

Comment: Yes its $9n-18$ for your last row it should be $4,2,n$ then see

Comment: No, it's (4,1,-n) my last row. OK, got it, thanks.